# Minted escapeinside doesn't work within a string

Tags: minted, italic

`escapeinside=||` usually works but not inside what for my programming language (SAS) is a string:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{book}
\usepackage{minted}
\usemintedstyle{vs}
\newcommand{\sasinline}[1]{\mintinline{sas}{#1}}
\newenvironment{sas}{\VerbatimEnvironment
  \begin{minted}[escapeinside=||]{sas}}
 {\end{minted}}

\begin{document} 

Is it possible to write \emph{percorso fisico} in italics here?
\begin{sas}
libname <|\emph{nome logico}|> '<|\emph{percorso fisico}|>' <|\emph{eventuali opzioni}|>;
\end{sas}

Leaving this as is:
\begin{sas}
libname corso '/projects/corsosas';
\end{sas}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: From the minted manual: “Escaping does not work inside strings and comments”

Comment: @egreg ... but David found a solution, anyway :)

Comment: You can improve the solution by doing `\newcommand{\metastring}[1]{\PYG{l+s}{\PYGZsq{}<}\PYG{l+s}{\emph{#1}}\PYG{l+s}{>\PYGZsq{}}}` and using `|\metastring{percorso fisico}|`.

Comment: @egreg Already done, of course! The only difference is that I called it `\sasstringemph` :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

An answer I know you will want to accept:

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{book}
\usepackage{minted}
\usemintedstyle{vs}
\newcommand{\sasinline}[1]{\mintinline{sas}{#1}}
\newenvironment{sas}{\VerbatimEnvironment
  \begin{minted}[escapeinside=||]{sas}}
 {\end{minted}}

\begin{document} 

Is it possible to write \emph{percorso fisico} in italics here?
\begin{sas}
libname <|\emph{nome logico}|> |\PYG{l+s}{\PYGZsq{}<}\PYG{l+s}{\emph{pineapple pizza}}\PYG{l+s}{>\PYGZsq{}}| <|\emph{eventuali opzioni}|>;
\end{sas}

Leaving this as is:
\begin{sas}
libname corso '/projects/corsosas';
\end{sas}

\end{document}
```

Comment: "Pineapple pizza" will become the new "ducks" for vote-attraction! :-)

Comment: It is important to note that `escapeinside` will also appear to not work if the document is in draft mode