# How to use escapeinside in a json file while using minted package

Tags: minted, pygments

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{minted}

\begin{document}

    This is a python
    \begin{minted}[escapeinside=||]{py}
    def f(x):
      y = x|\colorbox{green}{**}|2
      return y
    \end{minted}

    This is a json
    \begin{minted}[escapeinside=||]{json}
      {
        "hello":"world|\colorbox{green}{**}|"
      }
    \end{minted}
\end{document}
```

Got a problem that i can show the green box in python code, but i cannot get green box in json code. My guess is because the curly braces of json. I tried `\{ \}` but doesn't work.
[image]

Got another problem about the color of the json.

```
    This is a normal json
    \begin{minted}{json}
{
  "hello":"world",
  "hell":"worl",
  "hello1":"world1"
}
    \end{minted}

    This is a json with color problem
    \begin{minted}[escapeinside=||]{json}
{
  "hello":|\colorbox{green}{**}|"world",
  "hell":"worl",
  "hello1":"world1"
}
    \end{minted}

    This is a json with color problem but without green box
    \begin{minted}[escapeinside=||]{json}
{
  "hello":"world",
  "hell":"worl",
  "hello1":"world1"
}
    \end{minted}
```

Note the color of these three json
[image: color problem]

Comment: Question with the same cause: [italic - Minted escapeinside doesn't work within a string - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/384468/minted-escapeinside-doesnt-work-within-a-string)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The minted [documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/minted/minted.pdf) says "Note that escapeinside does not work within strings." (p. 20). Since `"world"` is a string you can't put any escaped code there.

It does work outside of the string. However, escapeinside still (incorrectly) causes the closing `}` to be highlighted as a syntax error. You can switch off the color box for errors by redefining the `\fcolorbox` command within minted environments.

```
\documentclass{article}
% from https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14166/red-box-drawn-around-question-mark-operator-in-minted-erlang-code
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\AtBeginEnvironment{minted}{%
  \renewcommand{\fcolorbox}[4][]{#4}}

\usepackage{minted}
\begin{document}
    This is a python
    \begin{minted}[escapeinside=||]{py}
    def f(x):
      y = x|\colorbox{green}{**}|2
      return y
    \end{minted}

    This is a json
    \begin{minted}[escapeinside=||]{json}
      {
        "hello":|\colorbox{green}{**}|"world"
      }
    \end{minted}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I tried this, and I can put a green box in a json. But the color of the json is wrong. I post the code in the question.